# app.yaml env_variables accessible as envs during cloud build steps

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

as described in title, some frameworks like Next.js or Nuxt.js require some env vars defined in `app.yaml` (only accessible at runtime) to be accessible during build step, mainly `npm run build`

the workaround I'm using at the moment is to define the same env vars in 2 different places `app.yaml` and cloud build trigger env vars: It is not ideal at all

Answer (score 2):

Agree, to maintain the same value in 2 places is the best way to lost the consistency and to create bugs. Thus, the best solution is to define only once these variables.

Put them where you want:

- In a file (.env file for example)
- In your trigger configuration
- In the app.yaml file

But only once! Then create a step in your Cloud Build job that parse the configuration variable file and extract the values to put them at the correct location before continuing the build process.

`grep`, `cut` and `sed` works well for this. You can provide file examples in you need to have code example for this substitution.

---

Edit 1

According to your comment, there is few things to know. Cloud Build is great!! But Cloud Build is also boring...

The env var management is a perfect example. The short answer is: it's not possible to reuse an env var define in the step N in the step N+x.

To solve this, you need to do ugly things, like this

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        MY_ENV_VAR="cool"
        echo $${MY_ENV_VAR} > env-var-save.file
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        MY_ENV_VAR=$$(cat env-var-save.file)
        echo $${MY_ENV_VAR}
```

Because only the `/workspace` directory is common between each step, you have to save the env vars in file and to read them afterwards in the step that you want.

About the `app.yaml` file, you can do something like this

`app.yaml` file content example

```
runtime: go114
service: go-serverless-oracle

env_variables:
  ORACLE_IP: "##ORACLE_IP##"
```

Example of Cloud Build step, get the value from substituions variable in Cloud Build.

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        sed -i -e 's/##ORACLE_IP##/$_ORACLE_IP/g' app.yaml
        cat app.yaml
substitutions:
  _ORACLE_IP: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: thanks for participating ! You're confirming my concern, but IMHO you are not providing a technical solution to this technical issue... some things to consider are:  1) whether or not env var programmatically defined during build step N (in `cloudbuild.yaml`) are indeed available in build step N+1. I can't find the answer, I'll test it if no one knows ; 2) what an actual flexible envvars extraction build step would be (in my question with `app.yaml`)

Comment: I hope my update answer better your questions

Comment: It does clear a few things up, thank you ! It is ugly as hell though. I'm going to look for a more elegant / flexible solution (like not being forced to name each variable in cloudbuild.yaml)